# mysql Sending data slow on inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tow **SAME** dedicated servers.
SQL-query on first work fine and quick.

```
SELECT 
  `store_item`.`product_id` 
FROM
  `store_item` 
  INNER JOIN `store` 
    ON (
      `store_item`.`store_id` = `store`.`id`
    ) 
WHERE (
    `store_item`.`product_id` IN (
     <many id (up to 500)>
    ) 
    AND `store`.`is_active` = 1 
    AND `store_item`.`is_available` = 1
  ) 
LIMIT 200 ;
```

[image]
[image]

On other server with **SAME** configuration and **SAME** version mysql:

[image]
[image]

What could be wrong?

**update 1.**
Table stucture are same in both servers.
**Structure Table `store`**

```
CREATE TABLE `store` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(75) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `delivery_days` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `currency_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `account_currency_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `minimal_margin` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `balance_money` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `total_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `added_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `empty_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `unknown_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_distributor` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `group` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sort` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `return_percent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `store_52094d6e` (`name`),
  KEY `store_41f657b3` (`currency_id`),
  KEY `store_145a375d` (`sort`),
  KEY `store_60ef08a5` (`account_currency_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=163 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Structure `store_item`**

```
CREATE TABLE `store_item` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(54) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `manufacturer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `num` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `price_in` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `price_out` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_available` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `delivery_days` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `discount_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount_code` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `store_id` (`store_id`,`product_id`),
  KEY `store_item_47799232` (`store_id`),
  KEY `store_item_44bdf3ee` (`product_id`),
  KEY `store_item_516bb1bd` (`count`),
  KEY `store_item_4ac7f441` (`manufacturer_id`),
  KEY `store_item_3aac1984` (`num`),
  KEY `store_item_52094d6e` (`name`),
  KEY `store_item_5c536bf3` (`discount_id`),
  KEY `store_item_65da3d2c` (`code`),
  KEY `store_item_5436e97a` (`modified`),
  KEY `store_item_64b158cd` (`discount_code`),
  KEY `store_item_5e0d2c81` (`is_available`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=16070923 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Yes, all indexes are same on both servers.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.